# 100% usage on few core while few core are idle

Tags: cpu

I am running ubuntu 18.04 and getting super high CPU usage in some cores while other cores are idle.

Htop command result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mas76.png)

Comment: One heavy process is using single core.

Comment: This looks like normal behavior with certain applications to me.

Comment: isn't there a way to configure so that the high cpu usage is more cores?